# how do i access a veriable inside a typedef struct inside a vector

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, sdl-1.2

how do i access a variable inside a data structure inside a vector. I am using SDL 1.2

I am making a vector list which contains a data structure inside it called SDL_Rect

SDL_Rect has 4 veriables inside it as shown below:

```
typedef struct{
  Sint16 x, y;
  Uint16 w, h;
} SDL_Rect;
```

i want to print out the "x" variable to the command prompt window. I am not sure what i am doing wrong?

```
vector< vector<SDL_Rect> >  hitBoxArray;
```

I have a vector inside a vector with the data structure inside it. i am not sure if this makes a difference or not when writing my code below.

```
void (randomFunction)
{
    int width = 10; 
    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) 
    {
        hitBoxArray.push_back(vector<SDL_Rect>()); 

        cout<<hitBoxArray[1].x    <---- this is the bit i cannot get to work
    }
}
```

if you are wondering why i have a vector inside a vector, this is because this code is being used to create a tile map and the first vector is for the rows and the second vector is for the columns and that bit of code works fine. its only when i am trying to access the individual variables inside the data structure that is causing me issues.

below is my working code and also includes the non working code inside comments if that helps.

Function code inside class: tileDriver.cpp

```
void tile::readMapFile(string filename)
{
    fstream map;
    map.open(filename);

    if(map.is_open())
    {
        map>>width;
        map>>height;

        cout<<"The width of the tile map is "<<width<<endl;
        cout<<"The height of the tile map is "<<height<<endl<<endl;

        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) 
        {
            tiles.push_back(vector<int>()); // Add an empty row for tile sprites
            hitBoxArray.push_back(vector<SDL_Rect>()); // Add an empty row for hit boxes  

            //this bit is the code that will not work for me
            cout<<hitBoxArray[1].x;
            //this bit is the code that will not work for me
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) 
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < tiles.size(); i++) 
            {
                tiles[i].push_back(i * j); // Add column to all rows for tile 
sprites
                map>>tiles[i][j];           
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < hitBoxArray.size(); i++) 
            {
                hitBoxArray[i].push_back(hitBox); // Add column to all rows for tile hit boxes
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"unable to load map for tiled textures! did you spell the name correctly?";
    }
}
```

header file: tileHeader.h

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<vector>
#include "SDL.h"
using namespace std;
class tile
{
protected:
    SDL_Surface*                ground;
    SDL_Surface*                grass;
    SDL_Rect                    groundTile;
    SDL_Rect                    grassTile;
    SDL_Rect                    hitBox;
    SDL_Rect*                   temp;
    vector< vector<SDL_Rect> >  hitBoxArray;
    int                         width;
    int                         height;
    vector< vector<int> >       tiles;

public:
    tile();
    void                        readMapFile(std::string filename);
    void                        printMap();
    void                        show(SDL_Surface* scr);
    void                        show(SDL_Surface* scr, SDL_Rect cam);
    SDL_Rect                    getHitBox();
    vector< vector<SDL_Rect> >  getHitBoxArray();
};
```

this is the error i get inside my compiler:

Error   1   error C2039: 'x' : is not a member of 'std::vector<_Ty>'    C:\Users\vishal\Desktop\game\game\tileDriver.cpp    52

i am using visual studio 2010 as my compliler

any help, incite or references to tutorials to help me solve my issue would be much appreciated :)

Comment: `hitBoxArray` is a vector of vectors. `hitBoxArray[0]` would be a vector. `hitBoxArray[0][0].x` would be the member `x` of the first element of the inner vector `hitBoxArray[0]`. Did you mean to write `vector<SDL_Rect>  hitBoxArray;` ?

Comment: since you have a  nested vector then you could use 2 iterators

Comment: Thank you soo much :D I was stuck on that issue for DAYS!!!!!  François Andrieux YOUR A LEGAND! all i had to do was hitBoxArray[0][0].x instead of hitBoxArray[0].x i feel soo silly :P